# Unknown character in textview text

Tags: android, xamarin

I have set text in text view

```
   TextView text = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.details);
   text.SetText(_text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

it sets unknown characters when displays

[image]

how to write unicode characters correct ?

must be text like this

[image]

Comment: whats the value in _text?

Comment: I've edited question and posted how it looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(_text));
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your characters/string, which you want to display, in res/values/strings.xml. Load it in textview like

strings.xml

```
<string name="unicodechar">my unicode char is here</string>
```

in Java:

```
String _text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.unicodechar);
textview.settext(_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a method like this to convert the string:

```
public String encodeUTF(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            byte[] utf8Bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

            String encodedStr = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");

            return encodedStr;
    }
```

Normally it will either need to be UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1

Answer (score 0):

Use a font like DejaVuSans.ttf. Copy this in assets folder. Then set the typeface of the text view as below. After this try setting the text.

`tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DejaVuSans.ttf");
   tv.setTypeface(font);`